Is there a way to replace a float element in an array with a string element in python?
I have two arrays in my code. One is a grid that is just filled with zero and the other is an array of characters with positions they need to be placed in on the grid. I included an image with my position array on the top and the grid on the bottom.

I'm trying to fill in the grid given the characters positions. For example, I would write this
grid[0][0] = pos[0][0] 
To place the character * on the top left. However it's giving me a value error
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '*'
I assume this is because the grid element is a float integer the position elements is a string. Is there any way around this?

You would need to specify what language you're using!  In some languages, having mixed types in an array is trivial, in others it is fundamentally impossible.

My fault, it's python, I updated the tag and the question title.

Please [edit] the post with text not images, and show a [mcve]  exhibiting the error.

This looks like a numpy array. All the elements have to be the same type.

So you need to change the dtype of grid to character.

Maybe there is a better way, I tried this:
import numpy as np

l =[['*',0,2],['C',1,0]]

arr = np.array(l, dtype=object)

alist = [(ord(i[0]), i[1], i[2]) for i in arr]
arr_f = np.array(alist, dtype=float).reshape((1,6))
print(arr_f)

slist = [(chr(int(i[0])), int(i[1]), int(i[2]), chr(int(i[3])), int(i[4]), int(i[5])) for i in arr_f]
print(np.array(slist, dtype=object).reshape((2,3)))

Output:
[[42.  0.  2. 67.  1.  0.]]
[['*' 0 2]
 ['C' 1 0]]

